# How do we trouble shoot a long-running NETMF program that stops in production?

Tags: c#, network-programming, embedded, .net-micro-framework

**Situtation**

I have a [FEZ Cobra II NET](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/482) running test code. It sends data every second to a server on the LAN. The server writes the data to a text file. After 27 hours and 97,200 successful sends, the Cobra stops sending. Clearly I am not going to debug for 27 hours, and I am not sure how else to trouble shoot, because standard software trouble shooting approaches do not apply.

**Question**

- If I were to write to log errors on the Cobra, how would I access them?
- Does NETMF have application logs? How can we access them?
- Is there an event viewer?
- What other trouble shooting / debugging steps are viable here?

**Code**

```
public class Program
{
    private static Timer timer;
    private Network network;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.network = new Network();
        p.RepeatedlySendDataToWcfService();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void RepeatedlySendDataToWcfService()
    {
        Program.timer = 
            new Timer(this.TimerCallback_SendSbcData, new object(), 0, 1000);            
    }

    private void TimerCallback_SendSbcData(object stateInfo)
    {
        SbcData data = new SbcData();
        this.network.Send(data);
    }
}
```

**Search and Research**

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=netmf+troubleshooting No results.
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=netmf+error+log No results.
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=netmf+remoting No results.
- [Can we access Cobra II error logs?](https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/forum/topic?id=15339)
- [NETMF - Debugging Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533004.aspx)

Comment: Can you make it send more often to see if it is related to the number of packets?

Comment: @peter_mcc That's a terrific idea! It seems so obvious now that you mention it.

Comment: "Clearly I am not going to debug for 27 hours" - Why not run the device with a debugger attached, and periodically check on it? At the very least you could check the application state once it fails, to spot variables with unexpected values for example.

Comment: @Snixtor That's a good idea. I will give it a go. Now, how do we remotely attach a debugger to an embedded NETMF program?

Comment: One of the articles you linked to states "After you deploy a .NET Micro Framework application, you can debug it in Visual Studio using essentially the same techniques you would use for any other managed C# application." I would think, worst case scenario, you have to use an emulator.

Comment: I notice on NetMF timer examples they wrap the target method in 'new TimerCallback()'. It may just be a network blip, which a Try/Catch around the data sending should handle. You could log errors to the memory card.

Comment: @WhoIsRich If you write an answer suggesting to log errors to the memory card, then I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: Try using WatchDog class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Fez has a memory card slot, you could log send errors to that:

```
private void TimerCallback_SendSbcData(object stateInfo)
{
    try
    {
        SbcData data = new SbcData();
        this.network.Send(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MyLogToCardMethod(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Mounting the card instructions are on the manufacturer site:

https://www.ghielectronics.com/docs/51/netmf-file-system

Comment: I know this is quite an old thread, but how about using the **Debug.Print** option while debugging? I just wanted to add this as for someone else coming to this thread, it may also be useful.