# How do we uninstall an application from a NETMF single board computer?

Tags: uninstallation, .net-micro-framework

**Situation and Question**

I have a [FEZ Cobra II NET](https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/482), to which I have deployed a small application. I wrote the application in Visual Studio 2012. Then I connected the Cobra via USB, and deployed to it via Right Click > Deploy in Visual Studio. Now I want to uninstall the application. How do we do this?

**Search and Research**

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=netmf+uninstall Nothing relevant.
- https://www.google.ca/search?q=netmf+install+uninstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MicroFramework .Net has only one application installed at time. If you want different functionality change source code and redeploy new application with VisualStudio and current application will be overwritten.

If you want to disable current application unplug device from electricity. :P

Comment: That sounds good to me. Thanks! I want to read the documentation on this.

Comment: Maybe you can also help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946632/strategies-for-troubleshooting-long-running-netmf-network-programming-in-product

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Micro Framework SDK, there is a tool, named **MFDeploy** , provided to deploy/upgrade device firmware. You can use this application to flash your embedded device's program memory.

Here's an overview: [MFDeploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc544593.aspx)